# Why if a tensor vanishes in some coordinates system it vanishes in all coordinates systems?

Tags: differential-geometry, tensors

If we take how the components of a tensor on a pseudo riemannian manifold transform

$$T'^{\mu\nu}(x')=\frac{\partial x'^\mu}{\partial x^\alpha}\frac{\partial x'^\nu}{\partial x^\beta}T^{\alpha\beta}(x),$$

if $T^{\alpha\beta}(x)=0$ in a certain coordinates system, we get that the tensor vanishes only in the intersection of the charts, but this nothing tells me about what the tensor does where $U_x\cap U_{x'}=\emptyset$, with $U_x$ and $U_{x'}$ neighborhoods of the two charts.

So, as far as I know from the above relation, my tensor is null in the intersection but may be non vanishing in the rest of the chart.

Do all the charts intersect somehow and thus going through all the charts I can see it?

Comment: It doesn't. If the components of a tensor vanish in some coordinate system, all you can deduce is that this tensor is zero on the neighborhood over which the coordinate system is defined.

Comment: Because in physics I have always heard "if a tensor vanishes in a coordinates system it vanishes in all coordinates".

Comment: The precise statement would be "if a tensor vanishes on a collection of coordinate systems which cover the whole manifold then it vanishes in all possible coordinate systems".

Comment: Wonderful, it was as I thought it should be! Thanks.